# DIV not showing full width. Why?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm working on right now: http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html

For some weird reason, the section **Como Fazemos** isn't showing full width just like the rest of the page. I haven't done anything different.

What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>bask.ra</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,200italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- COMECO DO NIVO SLIDER -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- FIM DO NIVO SLIDER -->

<!-- COMECO DO MENU FIXO -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

    var nav = $('.menu-fundo');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            nav.addClass("f-menu");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-menu");
        }
    });

});
</script>
<!-- FIM DO MENU FIXO -->

</head>

<body>

<div class="menu-fundo">
<div class="menu">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>

<div class="logo">

<img src="images/logo.png" />

</div>

        <ul id="menutop">
              <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#equipe">EQUIPE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#quem">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#como">COMO FAZEMOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#que">O QUE FAZEMOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
$("#menutop a").click(function(){
   var menuid = $(this).attr("href");
   $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(menuid).offset().top - $('.menu').height() }, "slow");
   return false;
});
</script>



<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
    <img src="images/slide1.png"/>
    <img src="images/slide2.png"/>
    <img src="images/slide3.png"/>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="o-que-fazemos">
  <a id="que"></a>
  <h1 class="o-que-fazemos-title">O QUE FAZEMOS?</h1>
 <h1 class="o-que-fazemos-subtitle">COMUNICAÇÃO + DESIGN</h1>


<div class="o-que-fazemos-content-1">

 <br />
<br />

<b>SUA MARCA VAI ALÉM.</b><br /><br />

<b><i>Consolidar uma marca vai além.</i></b><br /><br />

Além de um simples nome, razão ou definição, consolidar uma marca depende de uma experiência. E é a partir disto que as ideias surgem. Um novo conceito e uma nova definição de negócio.<br />
A <b>BASK.RA</b> nasceu para pensar, criar e gerenciar o posicionamento da sua empresa no mercado.

</div>


<div class="o-que-fazemos-content-2">

<img src="images/oqfazemos.png" />

</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="como-fazemos">
  <a id="como"></a>

  <h1 class="como-fazemos-title">COMO FAZEMOS?</h1>

  <div class="como-fazemos-content-1">
  <img src="images/comofazemos-content1.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="como-fazemos-content-2">
  <img src="images/comofazemos-content2.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="como-fazemos-content-3"> 
  <img src="images/comofazemos-content3.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="como-fazemos-content-4"> 
  <img src="images/comofazemos-content4.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="como-fazemos-content-5"> 
  <img src="images/comofazemos-content5.png" />
  </div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="quem-somos">
  <a id="quem"></a>

  <h1 class="quem-somos-title">QUEM SOMOS?</h1>
  <h1 class="quem-somos-subtitle">VOCÊ COM CERTEZA JÁ OUVIU FALAR DAS FAMOSAS FÓRMULAS DE BHASKARA.</h1>

  <div class="quem-somos-content-1">
  <br />
<br />
A equação completa de segundo grau agora pode ter mais sentido do que nunca. Pelo menos foi assim para a gente. Aprendemos a enxergar resultados claros e perfeitamente desenhados em cada problemática que analisávamos, e assim encontramos o X.
<br />
<br />
Dizem por aí que números não se comunicam. Já nós preferimos pensar que eles ajudam na evolução de qualquer negócio e podem se comunicar muito mais do que imaginamos, inclusive nos inspirando criativamente.
  </div>

  <div class="quem-somos-content-2">
  <img src="images/quemsomos1.png" />
  </div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<hr>

<div class="quem-somos-content-3">
<img src="images/quemsomos3.png" />
</div>

<div class="quem-somos-content-4">
<br />
<br />
<img src="images/quemsomos2.png" />
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="a-equipe">
  <a id="equipe"></a>
  EQUIPE<br />
<br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="o-contato">
  <a id="contato"></a>
  CONTATO<br />
<br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
<br />
Vivamus mollis sed lectus nec malesuada. Maecenas luctus suscipit varius. Sed bibendum luctus ligula, fermentum venenatis arcu interdum eu. Praesent sollicitudin tortor arcu, eu varius nulla consectetur ac. Etiam vel interdum urna. Sed dignissim, quam eu consectetur dictum, felis nulla suscipit dolor, ut tincidunt lorem nisi ut nibh. Mauris aliquam laoreet leo, id bibendum arcu ornare vel. Vivamus ultricies fermentum porta. Praesent et mi tortor. Quisque varius mi ac nibh ultricies, id faucibus orci semper. Maecenas sit amet consectetur purus. Quisque vulputate in felis sit amet convallis. Sed pellentesque, lacus in auctor tincidunt, eros quam pellentesque magna, at rhoncus nulla mauris quis lorem. Maecenas condimentum massa ut bibendum sagittis. Etiam non fringilla felis.
<br />
Curabitur rhoncus ut nibh eget interdum. Donec gravida, nunc gravida egestas tempus, leo urna vulputate ipsum, eget euismod leo enim et mi. Quisque non adipiscing nisi. Morbi a odio non lorem sagittis egestas vel et nunc. Vestibulum et turpis egestas neque blandit porttitor. Phasellus sem tellus, elementum id odio eget, scelerisque tincidunt lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus malesuada bibendum leo sit amet commodo. Vivamus vestibulum pulvinar nisl, eget scelerisque est dictum vel. Pellentesque posuere mattis ante, quis venenatis augue. Sed malesuada risus elit, vitae bibendum mi porta nec. Ut vitae purus felis. 
<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis placerat metus, a adipiscing ipsum. Aenean aliquam sed massa ut sagittis. Maecenas feugiat lorem consequat lobortis tincidunt. Ut commodo convallis turpis nec faucibus. Vivamus sed sodales diam. Donec eleifend nisl diam, ac luctus urna consectetur sit amet. Donec eget imperdiet mi, eu tempor ipsum. Nulla dolor eros, interdum vel viverra et, commodo a risus.
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


html,body {
    height:100%;    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    }

div {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    }

.login {
  display: table-cell;
}

logo {  
    border:0;
    z-index:9999;
    float:left;
    }

    hr {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 20px auto;
   height: 0;
   width: 50%;
   max-height: 0;
   font-size: 1px;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
   border: none;
   border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.menu-fundo {
    background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:fixed;
    }

.f-menu {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    } /* isso vai fazer o menu ficar fixo no topo */

.menu {
height: 100px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 9999;
background: #fff repeat-x 0 0;
position:fixed; width:100%
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    }

.menu ul li {
float: right;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:0px;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    }

.menu ul li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:3px solid #999;
    }

.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #6D6D6D;
    border-top:3px solid #EA0000;
    }


.row, .o-que-fazemos, .como-fazemos, .quem-somos, .a-equipe, .o-contato {
display: block;
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.o-que-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/oqfazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.o-que-fazemos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ffc709;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

.o-que-fazemos-subtitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }


.o-que-fazemos-content-1 {  
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
    width: 30%;
    }


.o-que-fazemos-content-2 {  
    margin-right:10%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    }

.como-fazemos {
    background-image: url('images/comofazemosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.como-fazemos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }



.como-fazemos-content-1 {  
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align:center;
    }


.como-fazemos-content-2 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;  
    margin-left:10%;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    }

.como-fazemos-content-3 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;  
    margin-left:3%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    }
.como-fazemos-content-4 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left:10%;
    color:#FFF;  
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    }

.como-fazemos-content-5 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF; 
    margin-right:15%; 
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    }

.quem-somos {
    background-image: url('images/quemsomosFUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    }


.quem-somos-content-1 {  
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#414042;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: left;
    }


.quem-somos-content-2 { 
    width: 43%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    }

.quem-somos-content-3 {  
    float:left;

    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    }


.quem-somos-content-4 { 
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    }


.quem-somos-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

.quem-somos-subtitle {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#414042;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }


.a-equipe {
    background-image: url('images/EQUIPE-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.o-contato {
    background-image: url('images/contato-FUNDO.png');
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    height:auto;
    font-size:28px;
    padding: 50px;
    }

.banner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    }

.banner li {
    list-style: none;
    }

.banner ul li {
    float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Josh, it works like a charm! But it has kind of "moved" the whole page slightly to the right. Do you know why?

Comment: Works in Version 33.0.1750.154

Comment: @GiovannaCóppola It's because of the padding. I moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are floating, you would add `width:100%` to them. In addition, you *should* also add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) in order to ensure that the width calculations include the padding to prevent alignment issues.

```
.row, .o-que-fazemos, .como-fazemos,
.quem-somos, .a-equipe, .o-contato {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't imagine that. Thank you very much, now everything's looking good!

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the `margin-right` of the class `.como-fazemos-content-5` then it is in one div.
No need of right margin here.

Comment: I have completely removed this margin-right property, but the whole page is slightly to the right yet. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue the last button wrapping to the next line? You could better write your code with a class to reuse on each defining the width of the items since they are the same width.

```
.como-fazemos_content{
width:20%;
}
```

Also consider using a font for frequently used icons like your plus symbol. Check out icomoon. You can make live edits to them similar to a font and use CSS3 pseudo classes to add them.